# A loan is being repaid by 12 annual payments of 3000 followed by 8 annual payments of 5000.

Tags: probability

A loan is being repaid by 12 annual payments of 3000 followed by 8 annual payments of 5000. If i=0.10, determine the principal and interest portions of the tenth payment and the 15th payment

im trying to find the original loan first, but i have no idea how to do it .

please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not supposed to provide a full solution and therefore the following is just a hint. Hope it still helps.

On day 1, you borrowed P (which is the initial principal) from the bank.

At the end of the 1st period (just before the start of the 2nd period), you owe the bank P(1 + r%).

You need to repay S, (which includes {repaying part of the amount you owed + the interest incurred} such that the amount you owed to the bank can be gradually reduced [and hopefully to $0 some day.]).

Hence, at the beginning of 2nd period (after the 1st repayment), you now owe the bank P(1 + r%) – S. This can actually be considered as the new ‘principal’. You should use it and re-do the repayment process.

In programming language, this is equivalent to

Input P, r, S, n=0

Repeat {P = P(1 + r%) – S} ; n = n+1 until P .LE. 0

Note-1: n is used to count the number of repayments.

Note-2: The rate is usually quoted in r% p.a. If the repayment is in month, the actual interest should be calculated as P(r%)/12.